# Error when installing lidR (Error in .shlib_internal(args))

Tags: r, lidar, lidr, rstudio

I am trying to install lidR in rstudio but i get this error Message.

```
installing *source* package 'lidR' ...
** Successfully unpacked package 'lidR' and checked MD5 sums
** using staged installation
**libs
Error in .shlib_internal(args) :
   C++14 standard requested but CXX14 is not defined
* removing 'C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/lidR'
Warning in install.packages :
   Installation of package ‘C:/Users/Downloads/lidR_4.0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

The version of R:
"R version 3.6.1

Comment: Why is it trying to install the package from *source*? Is it not on CRAN as a binary? What did you do to try and install this? What version of R is this?

Comment: I directly tired to install it using the .tar.gz file. I was getting the same error when i tired using from the CRAN.

Comment: "R version 3.6.1" - there's your problem. CRAN doesn't have binaries for old versions of R, so it tries to build from source, but you don't have the right toolset to build from source. Easier to upgrade R in most cases...

Comment: R 3.6.1 was released in July 2019. It is important to update both R and your packages regularly.